# Hive table on JSON file: How to parse optional fields

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, hiveql, amazon-athena

I am creating a table based on a big JSON file containing many JSON blobs.

Here are a few lines in the JSON file:

```json
{"user_id": "047b5bba", "primary_status": "available", "secondary_status": "available", "start_time": "2021-03-01"}
{"user_id": "047b5bba", "primary_status": "working", "secondary_status": "available", "start_time": "2021-03-02"}
{"useuser_idrId": "047b5bba", "secondary_status": "working", "start_time": "2021-03-03"}
{"user_id": "047b5bba", "secondary_status": "complete", "start_time": "2021-03-04"}
```

So you can see that `primary_status` is sometimes missing in the JSON blob.

I want to create a table with the following schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {{ params.namespace }}.fct_purecloud_users_incremental (
    `user_id` STRING,
    `primary_status` STRING,
    `secondary_status` STRING,
    `start_time` STRING
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '<file_path>'
```

But I found that the table in Hive is like this

```
user_id | primary_status | secondary_status | start_time
047b5bba  available        available          2021-03-01
047b5bba  working          available          2021-03-02
047b5bba  null             null               null
047b5bba  null             null               null
```

Looks like where there is no `primary_status` field in the JSON blob, it will not able to parse the remaining fields.

Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can query the original data directly without defining the schema (which is not consistent). Each line is a record that you can parse using the JSON functions:

The following example is creating a temp table with the records that you provided above and the query using *json_extract* returns the values or None is not available.

You can also write a CTAS to convert to a standard table if needed.

```
WITH example_table AS
 (SELECT '{"user_id": "047b5bba", "primary_status": "available", "secondary_status": "available", "start_time": "2021-03-01"}' as line UNION ALL
  SELECT '{"user_id": "047b5bba", "primary_status": "working", "secondary_status": "available", "start_time": "2021-03-02"}' UNION ALL
  SELECT '{"user_id": "047b5bba", "secondary_status": "working", "start_time": "2021-03-03"}' UNION ALL
  SELECT '{"user_id": "047b5bba", "secondary_status": "complete", "start_time": "2021-03-04"}')
SELECT 
   json_extract(line, '$.user_id'),
   json_extract(line, '$.primary_status'),
   json_extract(line, '$.secondary_status'),
   json_extract(line, '$.start_time')   
FROM 
   example_table
```

Comment: Thanks Guy! This is a good idea. I turned out using serdeproperties mapping and it works great.